# Buscar dados de uma página externa com file_get_contents

Tags: php, html

Estou utilizando o comando `file_get_contents` porque quero pegar uma informação de um site e colar essa informação na minha página.

Alguém pode me ajudar a implementar o código pra eu poder pegar essa informação?

```
// Endereço do site
$url = 'https://api.micetigri.fr/player/Leow%239880';

// Pegando dados do Site e colocando em uma String
$dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);

// Exibindo o retorno
echo $dadosSite;
```

Bom ele da print, só que não sei como faço pra pegar a informação que eu quero abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só queria reproduzir esse resultado no meu site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode capturar essa informação utilizando a função preg_match(), o código ficaria assim:

```js
$url = "https://api.micetigri.fr/player/Leow%239880";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
(bool) $operacao = preg_match("/<span id=\"ip_cliente\">(.*)<\/span>/", $contents, $dadosRetornados);

if($operacao)
    echo $dadosRetornados[1];
else
    echo "Falha na operação";
```

O primeiro parâmetro de **preg_match()** é a expressão regular a ser executada, como pôde perceber, utilizei uma `<span>` fictícia para simulação, observe no html onde é retornado esse valor e substitua.

Comment: Bom amigo, obrigado pela força!
seu código ajudou em partes, tipo tenho uma outra dúvida.Como faço pra implentar uma tabela completa nesse código ex: <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
 TABELA COMPLETA</table>

Comment: Isso pode variar muito de acordo com a estrutura da tabela, mas para uma solução geral, você poderia fazer um loop. Criei um array com todos as id's dos valores que deseja capturar e guarde os dados adquiridos com preg_match() em outro array a cada iteração de loop.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui amigo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Quase esqueço, existe também a função preg_match_all() que pode servir para você,  dê uma olhada http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php, ela irá retornar todos os valores que contém a expressão.